# For a linear recurrence sequence $(u_n)_{n\geq 0}$, can $\{i \mid u_i > 0\}$ be the set of Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, recurrences

**Question:** Is there a linear recurrence sequence $(u_n)_{n\geq0}$ (on the rationals, but I would also be interested by reals) for which $\text{Pos}(u) = \{i \mid u_i > 0\}$ is precisely the set of Fibonacci numbers?

*Additional infos:*

- It is well known that the set $\{i \mid u_i = 0\}$ is quite easy to describe (semilinear), but the sets with $>$ instead of $=$ can get quite weird.  For instance, there is a $(u_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with  $\{{k_1} < {k_2} < \cdots \} = \text{Pos}(u)$ such that $\lim_{i \to \infty} k_{i+1} - k_i = \infty$.
- This question is somewhat linked to the question "[For a trigonometric polynomial $P$, can $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} P(n^2) = 0$ without $P(n^2) = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167653/for-a-trigonometric-polynomial-p-can-lim-limits-n-to-infty-pn2-0)"
- The use of Fibonacci in the current question is not all that
  relevant—take the squares or the powers of two if it's easier.

Comment: How do the sequences you mention differ from what you want, if the choice of Fibonacci numbers is not important?

Comment: These $\text{Pos}$ sets behave as inequality of trigonometric polynomials; the example I mention for instance is such that $\text{Pos}(u) = \{n \mid n^2 \times \sin(2\pi\sqrt{2}n)<1\}$.  I want to compare these sets with sets that we naturally come up with, other linear sequences, squares, powers, …  Frankly, any nontrivial and natural set that is not expressible with $\text{Pos}(u)$ can be of interest.

Comment: Yes, I figured that your example would look like that, and a slight variation of that should give the Fibonacci numbers. It sounds like you are more interested in what can't arise rather than constructions.

Comment: I'm indeed more interested in what's *not* doable and thought Fibonacci is an example of that; but the question stands: if you can prove that Fibonacci is doable (or even an infinite subset of it), then please, by all means, I'm also interested in that!

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have a reference for your first "additional info"?

Comment: @Joël: Sure.  The first part is known as the Skolem-Mahler-Lech theorem.  The second part can be found in, say, the book of Salomaa and Soittola "Automata-theoretic aspects of formal power series", p.93.

Comment: Michaël, thanks a lot. I was asking for the second part. I'll check out the book by Salomaa and Soittolam it looks very interesting. I have recently been using the generalization in characteristic p by Derksen of the Skolem-Mahler-Leech theorem, and grew very interested in this set of questions...

Comment: Given what's known about the relationships between linear recurrence relations, exponential functions, diophantine sets, etc., I wouldn't be the least surprised if the set of all Pos sets coincides exactly with the Computably Enumerable sets.  (It's clear that any Pos set is CE and the reverse should run through a similar construction to the classic 26-variable polynomial inequality whose solution set is the primes.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Languages of the form $\{a^n \mid u_n > 0\}$, with $a$ a letter, are known as *unary Probabilistic languages*, and they are not even closed under basic closure properties (see Paz).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Solutions to (complex) linear recurrences are of the form

$$\sum_i c_i n^{e_i} \alpha_i^n.$$

To build such a function that is positive only on Fibonacci numbers, take $n^2(\alpha^n + \bar{\alpha}^n-2)+c$ where $\alpha = \exp(2\pi i / \phi), \phi = \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}$. For this to be positive, $\Re(\alpha^n)$ has to be close to $1$, which means $\alpha^n$ is close to $1$, which means $n/\phi$ is close to an integer.

Numerically, $c=8$ works. The values of $n^2(\alpha^n+\bar{\alpha}^n-2)+8$ are positive and drop toward $0.1043$ at Fibonacci numbers and they are quite negative at non-Fibonacci indices, with the nearest misses at indices of the form $\operatorname{Fibonacci}(n) + \operatorname{Fibonacci}(n-3)$, where it seems to takes the value $-118$ followed by indices of the form $\operatorname{Fibonacci}(n) + \operatorname{Fibonacci}(n-2)$, $-189$. A proof using standard results on simple continued fractions shouldn't be hard, and I'll try to fill in the details later.

---

I'll prove that $c=9$ works.

If $n = F_k$, the $k$th Fibonacci number, then we have an explicit formula $n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \phi^k - (-\phi)^{-k}\right)$ and the distance between $F_k/\phi$ and the nearest integer is $1/\phi^k$ as long as $k \ge 2$. The formula is incorrect for $k=1$, but $F_1=1=F_2$, so we can simply assume $k\ne 1$.

$$\begin{eqnarray}n^2 (\alpha^n + \bar\alpha^n - 2) &=& 2n^2(\cos 2\pi n/\phi - 1) \newline &=& 2n^2(\cos 2\pi \phi^{-k} -1) \newline & \ge & 2n^2 \left(-\frac{1}{2}(2\pi \phi^{-k})^2\right) \newline &=& \left(1 - (-1)^k\phi^{-2k}\right)^2 \left(-\frac{4 \pi^2}{5}\right) \end{eqnarray}$$

The estimate was that $\cos x \ge 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$.

When $k$ is even, we get that $-4\pi^2/5 = -7.90$ is a lower bound, so if we add $9$, $n^2(\alpha^n+\bar\alpha^n-2)+9 \gt 0$. For $k$ odd, $k \ge 3$ and then

$$-\frac{4 \pi^2}{5}(1-(-1)^k\phi^{-2k})^2 \ge -\frac{4 \pi^2}{5} (1+\phi^{-6})^2 = - 8.8.$$

So, if $n$ is a Fibonacci number, then $n^2 (\alpha^n + \bar\alpha^n - 2) + 9 \gt 0$.

---

Suppose $n$ is not a Fibonacci number. Let $m$ be the closest integer to $n/\phi$. Then $\alpha^n + \bar\alpha^n = 2\cos 2\pi n/\phi = 2 \cos(2 \pi m - 2 \pi n/\phi) = 2 \cos 2\pi n(m/n - \phi)$.

If $m/n$ is reduced, then because the denominator is not a Fibonacci number, $m/n$ is not a convergent to the simple continued fraction for $1/\phi$. This implies that

$$\left|\frac{m}{n} - \frac{1}{\phi}\right| \ge \frac{1}{2 n^2}$$

by Theorem 184 in Hardy and Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 4th edition. (In fact, this inequality is far from sharp for approximations to $\phi$ or $1/\phi$, so much better estimates could be used.) Multiply both sides by $2\pi n$:

$$\left|2 \pi m - 2\pi n/\phi \right| \ge \frac{\pi}{n}.$$

If $\left|2 \pi m - 2\pi n/\phi \right| \gt 1$, then $-2n^2 (\cos \left|2 \pi m - 2\pi n/\phi \right|-1) $ can only be small if $n$ is small, and those cases are easy to check numerically. Otherwise, we can use that when $|\theta| < 1, \cos \theta \le 1-\frac{11}{24}\theta^2$ from the first three terms of the power series, which implies that

$$\begin{eqnarray}2n^2 (\cos \left| 2 \pi m - 2\pi n/\phi \right| -1) &\le& 2n^2\left(-\frac{11}{24} \left(\frac{\pi}{n} \right)^2\right) \newline &\le & -\frac{11}{12}\pi^2 \newline &\le& -9.04.\end{eqnarray}$$

If $m/n$ is not reduced, then $m$ and $n$ share a common factor, and then even if $m/n$ is a convergent to the simple continued fraction for $1/\phi$, $\cos 2\pi n (m/n - 1/\phi)$ is too far from $1$.

Thus, if $n$ is not a Fibonacci number, then $n^2(\alpha^n + \bar\alpha^n - 2)+9 \le 0$.

Comment: Wow, mind=blown.  I'm not understanding it entirely yet, but nice feat!  Would that generalizes to any set of numbers that appear in a linear recurrence sequence?  I'd really love to see the "not hard" details :-)

Comment: If you try it over the rationals this quickly leads to the question whether $\exp(2\pi i/\phi)$ is algebraic, is it?

Comment: @Fan Zheng: The Gelfond-Schneider theorem says $a^b$ is transcendental for $a$ algebraic other than $0,1$ and $b$ an algebraic irrational. $\exp(2\pi i/\phi) = (-1)^{2/\phi}$, so $\exp (2\pi i/\phi)$ is transcendental.

Comment: I didn't write out the details for the nonreduced fractions here, but you pick up a factor of at least $d^2$ and closer to $d^3$ where $d$ is a common factor. Since the values for Fibonacci numbers are close to $-9$, multiplying them by $4$ makes them too negative. However, you might have to treat the first couple of Fibonacci numbers with small values of $d$ separately.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Perfect!  Can you state what is a sufficient property that would make this proof works?  Something like "There is a $\gamma$ such that $n/\gamma$ is close to an integer iff n is an element of the sequence", but more formal maybe?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you can fix any finite prefix with a rapidly decaying recurrence, it is sufficient that for some $\gamma$ and thresholds $\epsilon_0 \lt \epsilon_1$, for sufficiently large $n$, $n/\gamma$ is within $\epsilon_0/n$ of an integer for $n$ in the sequence, but not within $\epsilon_1/n$ of an integer for $n$ not in the sequence. Whether the numerators of the convergents of the simple continued fraction for $\gamma$ work depends on the coefficients of the simple continued fraction. You want them not to differ by a factor of about $4$ from each other, and it might help if they are larger.

Comment: I don't know whether the positive indices could be just the powers of $2$.

Comment: By the way, do you know of any reference explicitly stating "$n$ is a Fibonacci number iff $n/\phi$ is $1/n$-close to an integer"?  I've searched with no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a reference where this nice specific case is worked out. It does follow from some standard results, but it takes some extra work. A special thing about $1/\phi$ is that there are no semiconvergents that are not convergents since there are no coefficients greater than $1$ in the continued fraction.

Comment: Fascinating!  What do you mean by "follow from some standard results"?  The Theorem 184, or something unrelated?  I'm still amazed that this does not seem to be provable from first principles. :-)

Comment: Maybe it is easily provable from standard results although I don't think Theorem 184 is the most useful. My proof was surprisingly messy, so I don't want to post it. A simple proof would have simplified my proof here. Perhaps someone else could come up with a simple proof. This might make a nice question on math.stackexchange.com. If you ask there, please post a link here.

Comment: Also, as $1/\phi$ is algebraic, this does not provide a linear recurrence sequence with rational coefficients, right?  Any call on that case?

Comment: Yes, $1/\phi$ is an algebraic irrational, so $\exp(2\pi i/\phi)$ is transcendental, so it is not the root of a linear recurrence with rational coefficients. The construction I used generally produces transcendental coefficients, and I don't see how to get a similar construction with rational coefficients alone.

Comment: This is great, thanks!  Also, in Salomaa & Soittola "Automata-theoretic aspects of formal power series", p92, the statement: "If $S$ is the set of positive $n$'s such that $n^2\times sin^2(2\pi\alpha n) < 1$, then any two consecutive elements $n, m$ of $S$ are such that $(m-n)\alpha$ is close to an integer.", which is close to your statement here.  You wouldn't be aware of a book in which I could find results akin to this one, in particular to some converse of it focusing on the type of $\alpha$ (rational, irrational algebraic, transcendental)?  Thanks very much for your precious expertise!

Comment: I translated the statements into ones about rational approximations, and then used classical results on Diophantine approximation and the Farey sequence. Most of these classical results can be found in Hardy and Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers.* See theorems numbered around 180-184 which say in what sense the convergents to the simple continued fraction are good approximations, how good they are, how they compare to nonconvergents, and that very good approximations must be convergents.